# Strange Behaviour Class Objects Inside Union

Tags: c++, unions

Hi I wanted know the reasons of the following code

```
void main()
{
  class test
  {
    public:
      test(){}
      int k;
  };

  class test1
  {
    public:
      test1(){}
      int k;
  };

  union Test
  {
    test t1;
    test1 t2;   
  };
}
```

For the Above code it gives error "**error C2620: union 'Test' : member 't1' has user-defined constructor or non-trivial default constructor**"

```
class test
{
  public:
  //test(){}
  int k;
};

class test1
{
  public:
  //test()1{}; 
  int k;
};

union Test
{
  test t1;
  test1 t2; 
};
```

For the Above, No Errors.

I wanted to know the Reasons.

Thank you in Advance. :)

Comment: As the answers have already been provided I would just like to tell you that your first code has a wrong return type for main. main() should always return an 'int' in C/C++.

Comment: Just for the record: C++0x will have support for classes with non-trivial constructor/destructors inside unions.

Comment: Also in class test1 the ctor is named test instead of test1.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According to the C++ standard (§9.5.1, cited as well in other answers):

> A union can have member functions (including constructors and destructors), but not virtual functions. A union shall not have base classes. A union shall not be used as a base class. An object of a class with a non-trivial constructor, a non-trivial copy-constructor, a non-trivial destructor, or a non-trivial copy assignment operator cannot be a member of a union, nor can an array of such objects. If a union contains a static data member, or a member of a reference type, the program is ill-formed.

I first linked to the [Wikipedia article about POD types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structures) which states:

> A POD type in C++ is defined as either a scalar type or a POD class. POD class has no user-defined copy assignment operator, no user-defined destructor, and no non-static data members that are not themselves PODs. Moreover, POD class must be an aggregate, meaning it has no user-declared constructors, no private nor protected non-static data, no bases and no virtual functions. The standard includes statements about how PODs must behave in C++.

and

> In certain contexts, C++ allows only POD types to be used. **For example, a union in C++ cannot contain a class that has virtual functions, or nontrivial constructors or destructors**. This restriction is imposed because the compiler cannot know which constructor or destructor should be called for a union.

The first sentence of the second paragraph might make you think C++ only allows POD types to be part of a union. This isn't exactly the case as it allows a class with private members to be part of a union:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class test1
{
  int i;
};

class test2
{
  int i;
};

union test
{
  test1 t1;
  test2 t2;
};

int main()
{
  cout << __is_pod(test1) << endl;
  cout << __is_pod(test2) << endl;
  cout << __is_pod(test) << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

The program above compiled with MSVC++ prints out:

```
0
0
1
```

Comment: @Gregory: ignore my previous comment, as I'm now less certain about this. This is how I view the situation: the standard (in 9.5.1) doesn't explicitly forbid non-POD types in unions, but rather forbids types which have non-trivial constructors/destructors/assignment operators. This definition certainly overlaps with POD to an extent, but the definition of POD also forbids private member variables, which, as far as I can tell, are not excluded from unions. So it seems certain non-PODs are allowed in unions. But again, I'm not entirely certain about this.

Comment: indeed, union work with types having private member variables although  those would not be considered as POD

Comment: @Charles: A class with private member attributes and trivial constructor is problematic (members would be uninitialized), so I cannot really think of a real world example where that would apply

Comment: @dribeas: Yes, it would be odd.  But the non-POD class could still have member functions which make use of those private member variables.

Comment: Is this valid for C++11 ?@GregoryPakosz

Answer (score 9):

The C++ standard puts certain restrictions on the types of data which can be placed inside of a union.  In 9.5.1 the standard reads:

> An object of a
>   class with a non-trivial constructor,
>   a non-trivial copy-constructor, a
>   non-trivial destructor, or a
>   non-trivial copy assignment operator
>   cannot be a member of a union, nor can
>   an array of such objects.  If a union
>   contains a static data member, or a
>   member of a reference type, the
>   program is ill-formed.

So your program doesn't work because you explicitly define a constructor, and therefore your object violates the non-trivial constructor restriction.

Answer (score 6):

In C++, unions may not contain classes with (non-trivial) constructors or destructors. This is because the compiler has no means of telling which constructor or destructor to use when a union instance is created or destroyed.