# C++ initializer lists with unions, why different results?

Tags: c++, pointers, initialization, virtual, unions

I have the following program:

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>

class A;
class nih {
public:
    virtual void apply(A & a) const { std::cout << "generic" << std::endl; };
};

union niit;
class A {
public:
  int s; char kau;
  A() : s(1), kau('-') { }
  A(std::initializer_list<niit> k);
};

class sn : public nih { int s; public: sn(int x) : s(x) { }
  virtual void apply(A & a) const { a.s=s; } };
class kaun : public nih { char kau; public: kaun(char x) : kau(x) { }
  virtual void apply(A & a) const { a.kau=kau; } };
union niit { sn sni; kaun kauni; nih nihi;
  niit(const sn & s) : sni(s) { }
  niit(const kaun & k) : kauni(k) { }
};

A::A(std::initializer_list<niit> k) { 
  const niit *n=k.begin();
  for(int i=0;i<k.size();i++) {
    const nih* p=&n[i].nihi;
    p->apply(*this);
  }
}

int main(int argc, char**argv) {
  A r {kaun('a'),sn(91)};
  std::cout << r.s << r.kau << std::endl;
}
```

I get the expected result, which is `91a`. However, if I change the line

```
p->apply(*this);
```

to the following:

```
((const nih*)(&n[i].nihi))->apply(*this);
```

which should be replacement with an equivalent value, it no longer works, and instead it prints:

```
generic
generic
0
```

That is, it executes the generic method from `nih`. Why is that? I tried gcc 4.6 with option `-std=c++0x`, in case it matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A union can only be used with POD types, and as such cannot have members with virtual functions or nontrivial constructors/destructors, so this is undefined behaviour. Read (taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1873233/726361)) §9.5.1 of the standard:

> A union can have member functions (including constructors and
>   destructors), but not virtual functions. A union shall not have base
>   classes. A union shall not be used as a base class. An object of a
>   class with a non-trivial constructor, a non-trivial copy-constructor,
>   a non-trivial destructor, or a non-trivial copy assignment operator
>   cannot be a member of a union, nor can an array of such objects. If a
>   union contains a static data member, or a member of a reference type,
>   the program is ill-formed.

And

> In certain contexts, C++ allows only POD types to be used. For
>   example, a union in C++ cannot contain a class that has virtual
>   functions, or nontrivial constructors or destructors. This restriction
>   is imposed because the compiler cannot know which constructor or
>   destructor should be called for a union.

Comment: Isn't that C++03? IIRC, C++11 allows types with non-trivial ctor and dtor.

Comment: The restriction does not seem to be in C++11 any more. Gcc does not compile the code at all, if there is no -std=c++0x flag, complaining that classes with constructors are not allowed. With the flag it does not give even a warning.

Comment: @Xeo, Juho Ah, then consider this answer C++03 only. In C++11 does it also let you have unions with members that have virtual functions?

Comment: That I don't know OTOH, and I don't currently have the standard handy.

Comment: The program may be undefined for another reason. It inspects the nihi field of the union, whereas other fields were in fact assigned. The standard would permit inspecting common initial fields of "standard-layout" struct members of an union. A class with virtual functions is not "standard-layout".